# What statistics can compare individual survey responses & others that were measured as a group (from which we need to extract individual responses)?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, survey, survey-sampling

The organization I belong to studies indigenous populations through primarily survey research. One study for example aims to identify the relationship between culture and the evaluation of odors. We are looking for a statistical procedure that can be used to compare a larger amount of individuals. Some records were measured directly on individuals, while others were measured by a group spokesman. In the case of groups, however, individuals should be "downscaled" in order to be able to compare these data records with the data sets of individuals measured. The group speakers of a group are not always the same people from a particular group, but different people can respond on behalf of the group. The group size can vary within the measurement. A mean number of group size, ratio between man and woman and age is estimated per questionnaire/measurement (data set). Due to the difficulties collecting data in indigenous contexts, this is the only way we found to be possible. We are looking for a statistical method that can compare individual survey responses, if some were measured individually, and others were measured as a group (from which we need to extract individual responses).

Comment: You probably should have a look at [multilevel models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model).

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggestions how to apply a multi level model specifically in this case?

Comment: It seems to me you have clustered data with individuals nested in groups. On level 1, you have measures from each individual, and on level 2, you have measures that belong to the whole group. For such data, a multilevel model/hierarchical model/mixed model can be applied, with a dependent level (usually) on level 1, and independent variables on level 1 and/or 2. If this indeed applies to your situation, I suggest you rephrase it in multilevel terminology and be more specific about the variables and hypotheses.